# Laravel login and registration page not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, http-status-code-404

After installing laravel 7 version, I immediately installed `ui: auth`, ran the `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` command (for installation with bootstrap markup). Initially everything worked, I had no trouble, but now when going to the pages (Login, registration, reset password) I have a 404 error.

***web.php (route file)***

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/', 'MainController@index')->name('main'); 
Route::get('price', 'WorksController@index')->name('price'); 
Route::get('price/{slug}', 'WorksController@show')->name('single'); 
Route::get('about', 'AboutController@index')->name('about'); 
Route::get('news', 'NewsController@index')->name('news');
Route::get('news/{slug}', 'NewsController@show')->name('news_single'); 
Route::get('contact', 'ContactsController@index')->name('contacts'); 
Route::post('contact/send', 'MailSetting@send_form');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I didn't change anything, just before the line `Auth::routes();` I started writing my controllers and paths to them. Now if I run it in VCC (code), then on the `Auth::routes();` line it says that the function was not found, but if I open the same thing in VCS (Studio), then this error is no longer there. And when calling the `php artisan route:list` command, there are no paths for the login, password, register pages.

Comment: Try importing a use statement in `web.php` file just like what you have for Route facade `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` then run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan route:clear` and then check the routes again `php artisan route:list` does it show the auth routes

Comment: did you cache your routes at some point by any chance?

Comment: Thank @Donkarnash . All work !

Comment: Good you got it all working. Just noticed that you have a duplicate declaration for the `/home` route which should be rectified.

Comment: @Donkarnash, Yes - that's right, I noticed after I wrote. This something happened during copying, initially this was not contained in the file! But thanks a lot anyway!